# Writing a VS extension: Can you modify build files post build or deployment?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have an idea to create a VS extension that can perform a series of tests after a build event occurs, however; I'm new to extension development and am still trying to determine best approaches and what's feasible. Imagine one extension that can be configured to do the following after a build or deployment action has occurred:

1. Spell Check/Spell correction
2. HTML minification
3. Image optimization

Realizing there are a lot of requirements from the tasks above, I'm not what the best approach is for #2 and #3. For example, on html minification - is it possible to modify the output file after a build but not modify the original source? Is a VS extension the best approach or should I consider a post build hook for a CI server instead?

Comment: Perhaps `post build`(events) will not meet your requirements, you may need to write/use a VS extension.

Comment: That's been my initial thought for the project, but I really can't seem to find a non-hacky way to modify output files or create a new build output for a .net site like we do for desktop app builds.

Comment: Yes, indeed, VS extension is complex, and is not easy to write and develop. You may need to check the VS SDKs, if you finally choose to use VS extension. Here is the [reference for VS SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=visualstudiosdk-2019).